# Beaglebone: Backup image mounts root as Read-only

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, embedded, sd-card, u-boot

After I had completed creating applications for my BB white (running ubuntu), I created a backup of the SD card using->

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 of=/Volumes/BONE/bone_custom.img
```

Recently, I tried to burn this image onto a new SD card, using->

```
sudo dd if=/Volumes/BONE/bone_custom.img of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

Now, I see that the rootfs is mounted RO. I have made no change to uboot or fstab. Why is this?
I tried to remount (and force remount), but I get `"mount: cannot remount block device /dev/mmc*** read-write, is write-protected"`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does the SD card have this tiny hardware switch that protects it from being overwritten?

Comment: Its a micro sdcard with no lock.

Comment: Can you include the output of the `sudo fdisk -l /dev/disk2`?

Comment: See a dmesg output, maybe there is some warning about that. I suspect your data wasn't written out entirely and there is a filesystem failure. In this case, a filesystem check will help.